# Javascript : How to replace a substring in a string with % char's inside

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code to replace part of a string with another.
I do following way:

```
newTextStr = orgTextStr.replace(linkTextStr, shortUrlStr);
```

This works as expected, except when I have strings with encoded URL's, containing % in string, like for example:

```
orgTextStr="#nodejs #reactjs #remotework #remotejobs   https://fullstackjob.com/job/1Ud13TqJNn6S5JxzX3MrdqB0dEk/Sr.%2520Full%2520Stack%2520Developer%252C%2520Node-React%2520%255B100%2525%2520REMOTE%255D"
linkTextStr="fullstackjob.com/job/1Ud13TqJNn6S5JxzX3MrdqB0dEk/Sr.%252520Full%252520Stack%252520Developer%25252C%252520Node-React%252520%25255B100%252525%252520REMOTE%25255D"
shortUrlStr="go4.li/123"
```

works not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet is working fine. Could you please change `linkStr` to `linkTextStr`.

```js
orgTextStr="this url after https://fullstackjob.com/job/1Ud13TqJNn6S5JxzX3MrdqB0dEk/Sr.%20Full%20Stack%20Developer before"
linkTextStr="https://fullstackjob.com/job/1Ud13TqJNn6S5JxzX3MrdqB0dEk/Sr.%20Full%20Stack%20Developer"
shortUrlStr="go4.li/123"

newTextStr = orgTextStr.replace(linkTextStr, shortUrlStr);
console.log(newTextStr)
```

Comment: you are absolutely right
I found the problem now. For whatever reason, my linkTextStr is double encoded and then of course don't match. shame on me...

Answer (score 0):

If you expect your inputs to have URL-encoded strings - and if, for whatever reason, that's a problem for you - then consider using [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI).

EXAMPLE:

```
newTextStr = orgTextStr.replace(decodeURI(linkStr), shortUrlStr);
```